# Tela atualiza apenas uma vez ao usar múltiplas conexões socket

Tags: android, socket

Estou a criar uma aplicação android no qual troco dados com um servidor socket java no pc. E na mesma aplicacao abrirei algumas thread que rodam servidores para uma conexao direta com o android, recebendo dados intermitente.

O problema e que o servidor  para teste que tenho no android recebe apenas uma string e depois nao recebe mais.

Este e o servidor de teste que escuta conexoes vindo de um cliente socket java: Quando no cliente envio a string pela primeira vez, ela aparece na apk android, porem apartir da segunda ela na atualiza mais a ui, ate no cliente java envia e não aparece nenhuma exceção, na aplicaçao tambem nao gera exceção porem nao atualiza a ui. Talvez seja algum problema na classe onPostExecute, porem nao estou sabendo analisar. Tambem possa ser que a conexao ainda esteja aberta, tentei close() das diversas formas porem todas deram excessão e fechou a apk . Alguem poderia analisar o codigo e ver o que esta errado?

```
package com.example.palioteste;



import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Arrays;


    public class ServidorSocket extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private static final int portaServidor = 9879;
        private Socket conexao;
        private BufferedReader br;


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(portaServidor);

                //dados enviados para o servidor




                while(true)
                {
                    conexao = socket.accept();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conexao.getInputStream()));
                //String retorno =  "Dados Recebidos " + br.readLine(); //retornar ok

                //result = br.readLine();

               return br.readLine();

                }



            }

            catch(IOException e) {
                return e.getMessage();
            }

            finally{
                try {
                    conexao.shutdownInput(); // da certo mas quando tenta denovo a ui nao atualiza
                    //conexao.close(); //da excessão informa que a conexao foi reinciada
//br.close() // da excessao e fecha a aplicacao
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }





        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String resultado) {

            MainActivity.textorecebido2.setText("texto" + resultado);  
        }


        }
```

Aqui tenho a MainActivity

```
package com.example.palioteste;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private Button button;
        private TextView textView1;
        static TextView textorecebido;
        static TextView textorecebido2;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       ServidorSocket rodarServidor = new ServidorSocket();
       rodarServidor.execute();

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView1 = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textorecebido = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textorecebido);
        textorecebido2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textorecebido2);




        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                textView1.setText("Botao Cliquado");
                abrirSocket rodar = new abrirSocket();
                rodar.execute();
            }

        });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }






    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Comment: Você está usando `return`no `doInBackground` dentro de um laço infinito. Isso não faz muito sentido. O que você queria ali? Além disso, você está usando elementos estáticos na Activity e modificando eles através de outra thread. Isso tá bem errado. Você deveria estar passando mensagens em vez disso. Por que fez dessa forma?

Comment: Também tem a questão de você estar engolindo as exceções. Elas podem ser a chave pra você entender o que tá acontecendo. Use as funções da class Log (Log.d, Log.e etc.) em vez de printStackTrace.

Comment: Pablo obrigado pela dicas, primeiro, nao e necessario dar o return para o metodo onPostExecute? Não intendi isso("Além disso, você está usando elementos estáticos na Activity e modificando eles através de outra thread. Isso tá bem errado. ") o proprio eclipse indica a opção static e compila o codigo sem erro, ele ta bem errado porque tem uma forma melhor ou porque nao daria certo? Uso elementos estaticos apartir de outras thread no programa JAVA e funciona normalmente

Comment: Você está usando o return dentro do while sem nenhum condicional. O while é que não faz sentido, se na primeira iteração ele já vai retornar. Sobre o static, não vai dar erro agora, mas tente rotacionar o celular pra você ver o que acontece. O Android é programado em Java, mas a plataforma Android é completamente diferente do Java para Desktop. Usar elementos visuais como variáveis estáticas vai praticamente garantir que você vai ter um vazamento de memória se sua tela for destruída, e destruição de tela faz parte do ciclo de vida normal de uma aplicação-- pode acontecer a qualquer momento.

Comment: O que você deveria fazer é usar um [serviço](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=pt-br)  pra estabelecer essa conexão e receber esses dados. Esse serviço vai avisar a Activity quando chegarem novos dados e a Activity reage mudando o elemento visual que ela tiver que mudar. Uma classe não deve mexer diretamente nas variáveis da outra desse jeito.

Comment: Intendi sobre o static no Java Pablo, mas porque na Android o eclipse me indica metodos estaticos? Sobre o while, nao to intendendo pq se retiro o return, o metodo doInBackgroud me pede ele de volta, se coloco null, o onPostExecute me retorna null, me explica como tenho que fazer, sou iniciante ainda e faz alguns dias que to nessa pesquisa

Comment: Antes de mais nada, largue o Eclipse. Ninguém usa mais Eclipse pra Android e ele não é mais suportado pelo Google. Baixe o [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?hl=pt-br) e migre seu projeto para ele. O Eclipse está te recomendando tornar a variável estática porque isso permite à linguagem Java compilar o seu programa, mas compilar e funcionar são duas coisas diferentes.

Comment: Sobre o while, acredito que o que você quer é que algo rode indefinidamente e publique os resultados lidos da rede para a Activity para que ela possa atualizar a tela. O `doInBackground` tem o papel de fazer uma tarefa longa e publicar *um* resultado no final. Esse resultado é uma String, por isso ele te pede pra retornar uma String ali. Se você quer algo que execute por tempo indefinido, o que você precisa é de um Service, não de uma AsyncTask.

Comment: Pablo obrigado pelas dicas. Vou pesquisar sobre o service e tentar implementar. Sobre o uso dos AsyncTask pelo que vi na internet, todos os tutoriais sobre conexao socket no android dizia para usar ele. No envio de dados para o servidor funciona sem nenhum tipo de erro, por isso que achei que o erro seria em algum componente do codigo, entao AsyncTask nao funciona para o lado servidor no android? Porque o AsyncTask tambem tem o metodo onPostUpgrade

Comment: A questão é que o envio é um só, então não vai dar problema mesmo não. Mas o que você quer é uma coisa que fique rodando continuamente. O AsyncTask serve para fazer uma única operação longa e dar um resultado no final. O que você quer é algo que rode o tempo todo ao mesmo tempo que a aplicação e publique resultados várias vezes, em momentos diferentes. Isso é um Service.

Comment: Pablo, meu projeto e um pc de bordo que recebe valores de sensores conectados a um arduino. No meu intendimento, para enviar os valores dos sensores intermitentes deverei abrir um servidor para cada valor recebidos no lado android certo? Por exemplo, enviando o valor da rotacao do motor e da temperatura, terei que ter um servidor para cada um ouvindo em portas separadas nao e? com isso terei que ter um servico para cada?

Comment: Acredito que você pode criar várias AsyncTasks dentro do mesmo Service e mandar uma mensagem diferente para a Activity ao terminar de receber cada mensagem. Como o socket é bloqueante, você precisaria de várias AsyncTasks de todo jeito.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi. Esse servico e um tipo de thread ou devera estar dentro de uma thread?  Caso nao, eu posso criar a classe extendendo servicos, e colocar os AsyncTask para cada servidor que abrirei para escutar as conexoes, com isso em vez dos metodos onPostUpgrade responder para a thread principal sera os metodos da classe servico que respondera?

Comment: O serviço não é uma thread. Ele é uma coisa separada. Ele representa uma atividade que seu aplicativo faz que não faz parte da interface gráfica, e que deve continuar caso o seu aplicativo seja minimizado ou a tela seja desligada. Ele não roda em uma thread separada por padrão, mas pode rodar em uma thread separada se você usar um IntentService. A ideia é que você pode ter um while dentro do seu Service que faz o accept() e logo após passa uma mensagem para a Activity dizendo o que foi lido. Depois volta ao accept() (já que é um loop).

Comment: Comece por aí, de preferência com uma conexão por vez e, se tiver alguma dúvida, pesquise mais aqui no site ou faça uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Pablo, ate consegui implementar o serviço, a thread que roda o servidor funciona e tenho um botão que retorna os dados recebidos, porém não consegui implementar um método que fica em loop atualizando um textview com as respostas recebidas do cliente. Estou programando de um notebook dois em um com apenas 1 GB RAM, e não ta tendo como abrir o emulador nem ver o log cat,  por isso tenho que sempre instalar o apk num smartphone para experimentar o código! Se poder me ajudar com isso agradeceria!